# In c++, how to disable windows UAC control by program?

Tags: c++

In program C++, how to change the windows UAC to always notify or never notify.
Manually, I should change like this:

[image]

[image]

I found C# code from Internet:

```
const string UACkey = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System";
const string Subkey = "EnableLUA";
RegistryUtilities.SetValue(UACkey, Subkey, **1**, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord, RegistryUtilities.WOW64Key.Key64);
```

Does somebody know how to change into c++ code?

I tried to change the Registry with c++， but it does not work.

```
HKEY hKey = NULL;
LONG lResult = 0;
BOOL fSuccess = TRUE;
DWORD dwSize;

const size_t count = MAX_PATH*2;
wchar_t szValue[count] = {};

lResult = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System",  0, (KEY_WRITE | KEY_READ),  &hKey);


fSuccess = (lResult == 0);

if (fSuccess)
{
    dwSize = (wcslen(szValue)+1)*2;
    lResult = RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"EnableLUA", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)szValue, dwSize);
    fSuccess = (lResult == 0);
}

if (hKey != NULL)
{
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    hKey = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the UAC _is designed to not allow this_.

Comment: @KevinBrown Why there is C# code could do this??

Comment: So your question really is, "How can I set a registry value using C++"...

Answer (score 3):

To answer your stated question, you can set registry keys with [`RegSetKeyValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724921(v=vs.85).aspx), however you have to get past UAC in order to change the registry. To answer your implicit question, yes you could probably disable UAC programatically for malicious purposes, however you have to get past UAC in the first place to do so. Once you're on the other side of the airtight hatchway, you can do whatever you want of course. However you still have to get past the UAC hurdle.

Furthermore, I highly recommend you do a cursory google search before posting a question like this. The Windows C API is documented very well on MSDN.

Comment: I updated my questions and use RegOpenKeyEx and RegSetValueExW. But it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually very close;

```
DWORD val = 0;
HKEY uaKey;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System", 0, KEY_WRITE , &uaKey);
if(uaKey == NULL)
{
    //Handle error message here
}
else
{
    if (RegSetValueEx (uaKey, "EnableLUA", 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE *)&val, sizeof(val)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //Error
    }
    else
    {
        //Success
    }
    RegCloseKey(uaKey);
}
```